# Using a GUI when remotely accessing a Ubuntu server

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu-server

Is it possible to use a GUI (gnome) that is installed on another machine to display the contents of a server, kind of like a remote connection but the server itself does not have a desktop manager installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run a gnome-based app, the machine that executes the code must have the dependency libs (libgnome, libgtk, etc). If you are using yum, apt or similar, install the application and pray for a minimal dependency hell.

If you want to use a Gnome on a client to show server's contents, you are out of luck. The best effort you can do is use a remote file sharing (sftp, nfs, etc).

What I recommend from my own experience is install the software on server and use a remote connection, like remote X11, VLC or NoMachine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *sshfs* to mount servers directory on your client computer and browse it with your window manager.
You can also install *X Window server* on **client** and use *ssh* with option *-X*, so you can start on client computer all graphical applications installed on server.